# fulltext: this query very slow

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using this query but unfortunately it works slowly:

```
SELECT *,
    (MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('$word' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2
    + MATCH(`content`) AGAINST ('$word' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2
    + MATCH(`url`) AGAINST ('$word' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1.1
    + MATCH(`desc`) AGAINST ('$word' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 1.2) * `like`
    AS score
FROM `data`
WHERE MATCH(`content`,`desc`,`title`,`url`) AGAINST ('$word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 1000
```

the result of database is 15000. it means that 15000 records will be did but it takes about 25sec time for query. I am using PDO.

Comment: What about specialized full-text search engines? Sphinx, for example.

Comment: Please format your query properly. There is a long horizontal scroll.

Comment: Please provide table structure especally with indices, btw SELECT * is never a good idea!

Comment: this is my structure : http://vapasin.ir/images/str.jpg .

Answer (score 0):

You will need FULLTEXT indexes, otherwise the DBMS will need to search the whole table everytime. This does slow down the insertion of records. Note that a fulltext search on 4 columns always is relatively slow.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX indexTitle ON `data` (title)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX indexContent ON `data` (content)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX indexURL ON `data` (url)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX indexDesc ON `data` (desc)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX combinedIndex ON `data` (content, desc, title, url)
```